# why does the fog in 3d view look better than in rendered result

Tags: rendering

[image]Hi i'm trying to render a short scene with volume scatter and eevee. in 3d view the fog looks very smooth but in the final result you can see lines in the fog. I hope somebody can help because i really couldn't find anything that helped.[image]

Comment: Is the supplied image the final render or viewport?  Could you please supply both so we can compare?

Comment: ok thats what i see in viewport. in fact you can see a slight graduation of the fog in this picture too which i haven't at all when i look at it in blender

Comment: what i showed first is the rendered image. sorry i'm new here and don't know yet how everything works

Answer (score 1):

The "lines" you see are the dynamic range and the bit depth of the color.
Are you using JPEG  ? or PNG 8 bit ?

Try to render again using PNG 16 bit, or even the industry standard OpenEXR

and using filmic instead of standard helped a lot too,
standard only has 8 bits of dynamic range, while filmic have 24 I believe

**output properties > output**

[image]

This might help to improve your volumetric heavy scene.

try playing with the settings here,  Render - > Volumetrics (eevee)
especially the Volumetric Tile Size , if you set it to 2px, the volume will be very crisp, sharp and looks amazing, but will lag your blender & viewport. Increasing the samples might help too

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great and detailed answer. i'll try that immediately. Where is it possible to choose between filmic and standard?

Comment: i used png RGBA 16 bit and compression at 0% for my render

Comment: its in the render properties > color management > View transform

Comment: if you still find the "lines" , i guess you have hit the limit of sRGB.
you need to learn ACES colorspace (new hollywood industry standard), but its super complicated and hard, you can learn it later.

Comment: is there anything i can do about this sRGB limit because the lines don't disappear no matter which settings i choose.